# PDF to lucene document coversion using pdfbox

Tags: java, solr, lucene, pdfbox, apache-tika

PDFbox provides classes to convert a pdf to lucene document. Does it preserve the formatting of the document.By formatting i mean does it store details about the location and font type/size and other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it will remove all formatting and extract only textual content and make it searchable.  This content can be searched, and the original PDF can be maintained external to the index and returned with search results when a hit has been found.  Rebuilding a PDF from the Lucene index may not be the best approach, if that is your intent.

PDFBox is quite capable of extracting metadata, though, and it can certainly be used to index formatting / font / etc data, if you wish to be able to search on that sort of thing.

Comment: So if i need to develop a class that has stores the formatting capability i need to develop something from the scratch and i cant use lucene because it does not store formatting info. Can i use other libraries like apache tika which converts the document text to xhtml format but i dont know if that provides the capability of maintaining formating info and provides indexing capability too.

Comment: Again, a typical pattern of storage would be to simply keep it as a PDF, with a path to fetch the PDF stored in the index.  Storing the entire formatted PDF in the index is certainly possible, but generally not ideal.  Do you need to search based on formatting metadata?  What are you trying to accomplish here?  As far as Tika, yes, it is a good choice for transforming data for use with Lucene (that's what it was made to do!).

Comment: i m trying to build a java prog to compare two pdf files and display the result with some sort of highlighting.formatting metadata? i thought metadata was only to store details about the author and stuff.i started another thread about it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225774/compare-two-pdf-files-approach-using-java

Comment: which one's better itext or pdfbox?

Comment: I don't have a clear picture of what you are trying to accomplish from either this or the other question.  What are you trying to extract from the PDF, and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: i have two similar pdf's generated using diffent tools says ghostscript and adobe reader. i want to develop a jav prog that shows the differenced between these two. for now the differences are limited to the text objects.

Comment: If the differences are limited to text, what is inadequate about extracting the text and comparing them?

Comment: consider some case where the text is present but at different locations.if you extract text as whole how would you point that out?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to create problems before you've tried to solve anything.  It gets hard to solve theoretical problems with concrete tools (no, not [these](http://icanfixupmyhome.com/images/Magnesium%20float.jpg)) though.  I think we have left the scope of the question behind somewhere a while ago.  Pick a tool, and see what you can do.  PDFBox is a powerful tool, and probably quite capable of doing what you need, though it won't free you actually having to write some logic yourself.