# compare two pdf files (approach) using java

Tags: java, pdfbox, apache-tika

i need to write a java class that compares two pdf files and points out the differences(differences in text/position/font)
 using some sort of highlighting.
my initial approach was use pdfbox to parse the file using pdfbox and store the extracted text using in some data structure that would help me with comparing.
Is there any java library that can extract the text,preserve the formatting,help me with indexing and comparing.Can i use tika/ google's diff-match for this.
tika extracts text in the form of xhtml but how can i compare two xhtml files?

Comment: https://github.com/red6/pdfcompare, one more option to evaluate.

Answer (score 11):

I had to compare tons of pdf files in my project. my requirement was to compare the pdf files by pixel by pixel. After a lot of googling and as i could not find anything good, I ended up creating my own pdf utility for this purpose.

Please check this blog for more details & jar download.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/introducing-pdfutil-to-compare-pdf-files-extract-resources/

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, [pdfbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to extract its contents and then use [google's diff](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) to compare.

Comment: yeah but google's diff cant compare structured/formatted text

Comment: @Alvin I doubt that. Did you compare?

Comment: nope but it's very much on that google page that it compares plain text only.

Comment: @Alvin I thought you were extracting plain text using pdfbox.

Comment: that's the problem! pdfbox extracts plain text.i was asking for something that l preserve the formatting too. say apache tika preserves the formatting by creating an xhtml file but how would i compare two xhtml files? or i should create something from the scratch say preserve the formatting by saving the co-ods and comparing them

Comment: @Alvin I must have read the question totally wrong. But since XHTML is just a strict version of HTML, can't you use daisydiff? http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/

Comment: i think that help...can you gimme a min before i check this thing

Comment: @Alvin Let us know. I never used daisydiff.

Comment: wel i did a sample test.Daisy test changes the format of the html file when it generates the result. i mean the result has some elements with reduced font size etc.

Comment: @Alvin well..I am not sure what else you can do aside from trying google. Let me know if you figure something out.

Comment: sure...do you any library that converts pdf to html...tika and pdfbox are not good enough

Comment: @Alvin Sorry..pdfbox is the only thing I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [post](http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/09/comparing-2-pdf-files/) on comparing PDF documents. Take note of the line;

> PDF is a flexible file format in which you can do things in many
>   different ways. So you could create 2 different  PDF versions of a
>   file using Acrobat and Ghostscript (as an example). The files would
>   (hopefully) be identical. But the files would be different sizes and
>   the internal structure of each would be very different

Comment: yes i checked that but that dint really help....i need an approach so that i can develop some java program...ther's no direct opensource document comparator as far as i remember

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were able to solve your problem. Here is my approach to solve this.

First let's convert PDFs to HTMLs using [Pdf2dom](https://github.com/radkovo/Pdf2Dom) and then use [daisydiff](https://code.google.com/archive/p/daisydiff/) to generate comparison report in HTML. If you want a PDF then convert that HTML report to PDF. But keep in mind that PDF to HTML conversion is not 100% accurate due to complexities in PDF. You can also try another approach of converting PDFs to images and compare pixel to pixel and generate a PDF report. You can try [PDFcompare](https://github.com/red6/pdfcompare) library. It looks promising to me. Let me know if anyone already tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below given sample code for pdf comparison.

```
ZPDFCompare obj = new ZPDFCompare();
obj.pdfcompare("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\expectedFile.pdf", "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\actualFile.pdf", "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\expectedFile_Diff.pdf","C:\\Users\\tarun.kumar\\Desktop\\actualFile_Diff.pdf");
```

zeonpad provided the free java api for pdf comparison.

Comment: Please just note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)